# PHP Prepared Update Statement -Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I have the following extract of code, nested in a prepared SELECT statement:

```
$updQuery ="UPDATE `BookingData` SET `LastPrice`=1.0";
if ($stmtUpd = $mysqli->prepare($updQuery)) {
    printf ("now binding...");
        ...

 }else
 {
    trigger_error($stmtUpd->error, E_USER_ERROR);     
 }
```

Which is throwing the error:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in ..

if I replace the query to a SELECT statement it works correctly:

```
$updQuery ="SELECT `LastPrice` FROM `BookingData` ";
if ($stmtUpd = $mysqli->prepare($updQuery)) {
printf ("now binding...");
            ...

 }else
 {
    trigger_error($stmtUpd->error, E_USER_ERROR);     
 }
```

**BookingData** is a table in a MySQL Database, with the field **LastPrice** having type **decimal** .

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: probably because of the missing WHERE clause, if you have more than 1 row.

Comment: I changed it to: $updQuery ="UPDATE `BookingData` SET `LastPrice`=1.0 WHERE 1"; and it still didn't work so I guess that's not the problem

Comment: you need to check for the real error; I don't think you are.

Comment: `WHERE 1` doesn't do anything really. You want to use something like `WHERE col_x ='???'` using an actual column name.

Comment: WHERE 1 us  equivalent to WHERE 1=1 in MySQL which will load all rows as I am trying to do

Comment: Please show all the error message you have truncated an important info .... and show also where you define $mysqli

Comment: @scaisEgge just the name of the file was truncated, no other errors were visible. The error was related to the security privileges of the user, there was no indication of this from the error though.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: no where clause is fine, unless you're running in (literally) `i_am_a_dummy` mode, which disallows non-where'd queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, the problem was that the MySQL user I was using hadn't been given UPDATE privileges but has SELECT rights by default, pity the error doesn't point to anything permission related.